# How do you set state when navigating with TouchableOpacity react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, touchableopacity

I am using a TouchableOpacity and when I press it I want to set some state and then pass that state down as a prop when I navigate. However when I try it navigates before the state is updated. Here is my code:

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

type props = {
    route: any,
}

const Identity = ({route}: props) => {
    const [identity, setIdentity] = useState('')

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const {name, date} = (route.params)

    const [loaded] = useFonts({
        Poppins_600SemiBold,
    });

    if (!loaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <PageIndicator currentPosition={2}/>
            <View>
                <Text style={{
                    marginTop: 100,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    paddingLeft: 30
                }}
                >
                    What's your gender?
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}

                        onPress={() => {
                            setIdentity('Man');
                            navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
                                setIdentity('Man')
                            });
                            navigation.navigate('InterestedIn', {
                                name,
                                date,
                                identity
                            });
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#fc92c5',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,

                        }}
                        >
                            Man
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setIdentity('Woman')
                            navigation.navigate('InterestedIn', {
                                name,
                                date,
                                identity
                            })
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#fc92c5',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,
                        }}
                        >
                            Woman
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setIdentity('Other')
                            navigation.navigate('InterestedIn', {
                                name,
                                date,
                                identity
                            })
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#fc92c5',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,
                        }}
                        >
                            Other
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default Identity;
```

Here is where my code navigates to:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {useFonts} from 'expo-font';
import {Poppins_600SemiBold} from '@expo-google-fonts/poppins';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import PageIndicator from './PageIndicator';

type props = {
    route: any,
}

const InterestedIn = ({route}: props) => {
    const [interest, setInterest] = useState('')

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const {name, date, identity} = (route.params)

   // console.log(name)
   // console.log(date)
    console.log("identity", identity)
    console.log(route.params)

    const [loaded] = useFonts({
        Poppins_600SemiBold,
    });

    if (!loaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <PageIndicator currentPosition={3}/>
            <View>
                <Text style={{
                    marginTop: 100,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    paddingLeft: 30
                }}
                >
                    Who do you want to date?
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate('navigator')
                            setInterest('Men')
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#FFF',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,

                        }}
                        >
                            Men
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate('navigator')
                            setInterest('Women')
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#FFF',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,
                        }}
                        >
                            Women
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate('navigator')
                            setInterest('Everyone')
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{
                            color: '#FFF',
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
                            fontSize: 15,
                        }}
                        >
                            Everyone
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default InterestedIn;
```

And here is the console log:

```
    identity
Object {
  "date": 2002-04-03T23:00:00.000Z,
  "identity": "",
  "name": "Ol",
}
```

I tried to add an event listener to the navigation but that didnt work. Do you have any suggestions, or maybe better ways to give text to a touchable opacity rather than this way? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might use `useEffect`, based on the ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), that would look like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (identity) {
        navigation.navigate('InterestedIn', {
             name,
             date,
             identity
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will that not navigate as soon as my component loads though?

Comment: I get this error if i do Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
 for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: You need to check that the state value you're interested in has changed before navigating. I updated the code sample, you might need to adapt it to suit your needs